# Why do Minecraft double doors behave the way they do with redstone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've seen videos that explain how to make redstone double doors, but none of them really explain *why* redstone double doors work that way, just that they do.

Is there an explanation for their behaviour?

Comment: This question is obsolete as of patch 1.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Doors have two states, "open" and "closed". When you place two doors next to each other, the game automatically moves the 2nd door 90* and swaps the state (if it didn't, you'd just have two identical doors next to each other).

In manual use, the state isn't important, but as soon as you connect the door to redstone, it becomes very important: doors without charge go to the "closed" state, and doors with charge go to the "open" state. Because the doors are not next to each other in their "closed" state, you get the weird behavior you've observed.

[image: Pictures incoming.]

Comment: What does this mean about firing arrows through the window?

Comment: @mbreadley -- What?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer, arrows can be fired in *one* direction through doors, so it's important to place the doors from outside your house. Otherwise the archer skeletons could fire *in* at you :) I don't know the implications of double-doors or redstone, however.

Comment: Calling the two states "open" and "closed" is rather arbitrary: you could just as well call them "counterclockwise" and "clockwise".

Comment: @Kevin -- I imagine most doors will be set in walls, which makes the distinction strictly less than arbitrary.

Comment: It's possible to place a door in a wall so that the states are swapped. (You have to remove the wall next to the door to avoid the double-door rule, and stand sideways while placing it, though.)